# How does gcc on Linux know it is libc.so.6 that contains printf function?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compilation, linker

If I do `gcc hello_world.c`, how does `gcc`/`ld` know it is `libc.so.6` that should be linked against? Does `gcc`/`ld` go through the default shared library paths(however the linker was configured, plus some `gcc` additional flavors), and then scan symbol table of each `.so` file?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. Unless you use `-nostdlib`, `-lc` is in the default libraries GCC passes to the linker for link commands. For other libraries, you need to explicitly request them when linking.

Comment: This does not answer the question. `-lc` is not a library. It is a command line switch. It tells the linker to look for a file named `libc.something`. The paths where it looks for it and the possible values of `something` are either built into the linker or configured when it is built, unless modified by environment variables or switches.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Formally, `-lc` **is the library**. Whether any such file exists is implementation defined. For gcc yes one does, but in any case I think it's a reasonable way to talk about the situation.

Comment: [Formally](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc.pdf), in `-lc`, “c” is the name of the library (page 211). But it is not the library; a sentence there says “The linker searches a standard list of directories for the library.” So the library is in fact a file in some directory. Moreover, the question asks how `gcc` or `ld` knows it is `libc.so.6` that should be linked against. By default, `gcc`, when linking object it knows derives from C sources, passes `-lc` or some equivalent to the linker. The linker has lists of standard system directories and extensions that it searches,…

Comment: … and those lists are dependent on the target platform and the setting used in building the GNU tools. I would answer the question except I do not know about the `.6` part of `.so.6`. I expect the linker searches for `.so` files, but I do not know if its search would directly include `.so.6` files or the linker somehow finds it because it is referred to in some other file. (E.g., a `libc.so` stub that refers to `libc.so.6`.)

Comment: I'm thinking [It is unspecified whether the libraries libc.a, libl.a, libm.a, libpthread.a, librt.a, libtrace.a, libxnet.a, or liby.a exist as regular files. The implementation may accept as -l option-arguments names of objects that do not exist as regular files.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/c99.html).

Comment: @EricPostpischil: The linker does not search `.so.6` whatsoever. How it searches libraries is outside the scope of this question. If you're interested in it you can post a question specifically asking that (including how the `.version` stuff works) and I'll try to answer well.

Comment: It is not outside the scope of the question; it is the question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I don't read it that way, but I guess I see how you could. I read it as a general question (not specific to `printf`) of how gcc finds the appropriate library for a function you call, where the answer is basically "it doesn't, the std library is just always available".

Comment: thanks for the answer and comments, the discussion and the references are quite helpful. Now my understanding is, `-lc` is included in actual linking command generated by `gcc` by default, then linker will be searching for `libc.something`, where `something` will be `.so` or `.a`, depending on the linking being shared or static, is that correct? And the linker will include add the libraries mentioned by `-l` flag into the NEEDED entry into `.dynamic` section of output file, regardless whether the symbols in that library is really referenced or not, correct?

Comment: And, I still do not understand how the `.6` part come into the picture. Maybe that's the `.version` that @R.. mentioned?

Comment: @QnA: *where something will be .so or .a, depending on the linking being shared or static, is that correct?*

Yes, that's correct.  For instance, if your compiler command starts with `$(CC) -shared -fPIC ...` then it will take the `.so` file(s), since you ordered the GCC compiler to go for shared libraries.

Comment: @GeertVc: `-shared` does not mean to go for shared libraries. It means to produce a shared library.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE: That is correct, `-shared` asks the linker to create a `.so` file for your library. But I thought that this also implied that all the other libraries involved in creating your own library had to be `.so` files too. That seems to be incorrect according [this discussion](https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc/2001-07/msg01444.html)  (read especially the two answers)...  Continuation below....

Comment: ...Yes, I did some investigation about this subject... Using the linker flags `-Wl,-Bstatic <lib>` and/or `-Wl,-Bdynamic <lib>` (syntax can differ a bit apparently, depending on the OS you're working on) you can mix the two types of libraries. However, ***many discourage*** the use of mixed libraries because of possible backwards incompatibility issues.